# how to insert data into database using MEAN stack (MySQL, Express, Angular, Node)

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, mean-stack

**How to insert data into database using MEAN stack (MySQL, Express, Angular, Node)?
I am facing the problem at the time of insertion. Please help me to solve this. Here is my code. I'm newbie in MEAN.**

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="bookitnow">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title> Registration Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="bookitnow" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" ng-model="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" ng-model="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" ng-model="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
    </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>

</form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express    = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : '',
   database : 'bookitnow'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
   if (!err)
     console.log('Database is connected');
   else
     console.log('DB connection error.');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public' + 'index.html');
});


app.post('/index.html', function(req, res, next) {
  var data = req.body;
    console.log('request received:', data);

    connection.query('INSERT INTO register SET ?', data, function(err,res){
      if(err) throw err;
        console.log('record inserted');
    });  

app.listen(5500);

console.log('Hi from server.js');
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('bookitnow',[]);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http){
        $scope.submit = function() {

            var data = {
                    fName   : $scope.fname, 
                    lName   : $scope.lname,
                    email   : $scope.email,
                    phone   : $scope.phone
                }   
            };

            $http.post('/index.html', &scope.data)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.result = data;
                    console.log("inserted successfully")
                })
                .error(function(data, status, header, config){
                    $scope.result = "Data: " + status;


                });
```

Comment: what are you getting in body `console.log('request received:', data);`?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller.js, try the following and see what happens.

```
var app = angular.module('bookitnow',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.submit = function() {

        var data = {
            fName   : $scope.fname, 
            lName   : $scope.lname,
            email   : $scope.email,
            phone   : $scope.phone
        }; 

        $http
            .post('/index.html', data)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }, function(response){
                console.log(response)
            });
     };
});
```

Comment: I did the same, as you said... Now controller showing the error:               POST http://localhost:5500/index.html net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
controller.js:17 failure...

Comment: Help me what should I do now?

Comment: Are you sure your server is running?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. When i am refreshing the browser server got disconnected. What's the next move?

Comment: Just made a change to the code, forgot a closing bracket on the last line. Try using it again.

Comment: No. still not working. so i removed the controller.js and made some changes in server.js with index.html. Now it is working