# How do I validate Inputed data in CRUD application using MEAN stack?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

[image: Image 1]

I am working on CRUD application and above one is snapshot of its design and 
I have done validation for updating in this application.
I go through from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258479/how-to-insert-data-into-database-using-mean-stack-mysql-express-angular-node).

But I did not rectify my problems.

I want to validate it during inputing means when I does not input anything in text box then it would not add it in database and give proper error on console.
Below is my code Image:

[image: controller.jpg]

[image: server.jpg]

[image: j]

Comment: [Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validation
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-validation

Next time include code examples in your question. It's hard to give you any specific answer seeing only random screenshots of your editor windows with a tiny font as JPEGs.